# Characterization of the finite-dimensional $l_\infty$, $l_1$, $l_p$ up to a linear isometry

Tags: geometry, banach-spaces

There are many different ways to endow the finite dimensional vector space $\mathbb R^n$ with the structure of Banach space, in particular, one can consider the standard norms
$$
||x||_\infty=\max_{i=1,...,n}|x_i|, \quad
||x||_1=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|, \quad
||x||_p=\sqrt[p]{\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p}.
$$
In general, the corresponding Banach spaces are not isometrically isomorphic.

> Is it possible to understand geometrically, whether a given (abstract) norm $||\cdot||$ on $\mathbb R^n$ is isometrically isomorphic to $||\cdot||_\infty$ (i.e. turns $\mathbb R^n$ into a Banach space, isometrically isomorphic to the finite-dimensional $\ell_\infty$)?

(Evidently, the unit ball of such a norm must have $2^n$ extreme points, but this is not a characterization...)

And the same question for $||\cdot||_1$ (with $2n$ extreme points), and for $||\cdot||_p$.

I asked this now in [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168095/characterization-of-l-p-up-to-a-linear-isometry).

Comment: You've not specified what kind of classification is satisfactory for you. In categorical terms, in terms of bases or something else. Anyway good question (+1).

Comment: Initially I thought that the geometric properties of the unit ball (extreme points, facets, etc.) must give enough information. But as far as I understand, only for the finite-dimensional case and only for  $p\in\{1,\infty\}$. Anyway, the question is open, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168095/characterization-of-l-p-up-to-a-linear-isometry.